# Java MouseListener newbie

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I am pretty new to java, and I am trying to make a MouseListener so that I can draw lines in a JFrame. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Liner extends JComponent implements MouseListener{

static int MouseX1, MouseY1, MouseX2, MouseY2;
static JFrame window = new JFrame();
static JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public static void main(String[] args){
    panel.addMouseListener(this);
    window.add(panel);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.pack();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawLine(MouseX1,MouseY1,MouseX2,MouseY2);
}


public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    MouseX1 = e.getX();
    MouseY1 = e.getY();
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    MouseX2 = e.getX();
    MouseY2 = e.getY();
}    
}
```

I have been getting the same errors a lot, including

> error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
>           panel.addMouseListener(this);

and

> error: cannot find symbol public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

(the second one refers to "MouseEvent").

Comment: `this` doesn't exist within a `static` context, `this` refers to the current instance of an object, but since you're in a `static` context, no object exists

Comment: For the second error you should `import java.awt.event.*` which contains `MouseEvent` class. For the first error you can't refer this in a static method, probably you meant `panel.addMouseListener(new Liner())`.

Comment: As to your second problem, add `import java.awt.event.*` to your imports.  A `import` statement is not recursive, it only imports the classes from the specified package (when used with a wild card)

Comment: @Jack That last part (*`panel.addMouseListener(new Liner())`*) is actually misleading, as then the OP's paint code won't work. May they should actually make `panel` and instance of `Liner` and register the `MouseListener` within it's constructor instead?

Comment: When performing custom painting in Swing, it is generally encouraged to override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.  It's also (highly) recommended that you call the paint methods `super` method, in order to maintain the integrity of the painting process.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer: that was exactly what I was answering but the question has been closed before I ended the answer so I had to shorten it to a comment.

Comment: @Jack Unfortunately it's not what your comment said :P